# CSS Drop Down Menu : nav ul ul li Moved to Right

Tags: css, html

Here is an image :

[image: Drop Down Menu]
The problem is the `nav ul ul li` moved to the right, as seen in the image, the tab "Contact" moved to the right, and thus the size was not what I want. I want the tab "Contact" to have the same size of "About".

This is the code of mine :

(HTML)

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

(CSS)

```
/* Basic Styling */

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
}

/* Menu Styling */

nav > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:#dddddd;
  text-align:center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color:#aaaaff;
}

nav ul ul {
  display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul > li {
  display:block;
  width:400px;
  height:80px;
  line-height:80px;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}

nav ul ul li,
nav ul ul li a {
  display:block;
}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RM3Lz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the width and heights for the list items in the inner ul were different than the ones in the outer ul.  To fix the indentation I set padding left to 0 for your inner ul.

The code below should work. Also here is a link to my codepen http://cdpn.io/ivJxc

```
/* Basic Styling */

a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:inherit;
}

/* Menu Styling */

nav > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color:#aaaaff;
}

nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    padding-left:0; 
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul > li {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  padding:0px;
  text-align:center;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Actually how can I make `nav ul ul ul` display at the right of `nav ul ul`?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to add another level to your navigation? Currently there is no nav ul ul ul.

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: I would just add another level to the menu and instead of setting the `padding-left: 0px;` for li, set it equal to the distance you want to push the element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to add one additional rule, it is something like below

```
ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
```

simply add this rule in, then it will work. I consider it is better to give a rule on ul li ul, as it is the container of its li. Later, you can have more control over it.

check the jsFiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/wenbolovesnz/J7T9M/

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul ul li{
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}
nav ul ul {
    padding: 0;
  display:none;
}
```