# CSS dropdown menu alignment issues

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, alignment

I'm working on a pure CSS dropdown menu but ran into some alignment issues.

Specifically: the sub-menu items get moved over to the right when hovering over their respective menu item. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fhakjnhe/5/

HTML

```
<body>

<header>

<div id="menustrip">

                <div id="logo_container">
                    <h1>LOGO</h1>                   
                </div>

                <div id="menu">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="active-page" href="#">AAA</a></li
                            ><li><a href="#">BBB</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="background-color:red;">A</li>
                                    <li>B</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li
                            ><li><a href="#">CCC</a></li
                            ><li><a href="#">DDD</a></li
                            ><li><a href="#">EEE</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li style="background-color:blue;">A2</li>
                                    <li>B2</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li
                            ><li><a href="#">FFF</a></li
                            ><li><a id="quote-page" href="#">GGG</a></li>
                        </ul>


                    </nav>              
                </div>

            </div>
```

Related CSS

```
header #menustrip #menu nav ul
        {
            list-style: none;               
            position: relative;              
        }

            header #menustrip #menu nav ul li
            {
                display: inline-block;                  
            }

                header #menustrip #menu nav a
                {
                    display: block;
                    color: #1d120c;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    padding: 0 /*15px*/10px;
                    margin: 0;
                    border: 2px solid transparent;
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav a:hover 
                {
                    border-left: 2px solid #97bc14;
                    border-right: 2px solid #97bc14;
                    color: #97bc14
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav a#active-page
                {
                    color: #97bc14
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav a#quote-page
                {
                    margin-left: 15px;
                    border: 2px solid #97bc14;
                    color: #97bc14
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav a#quote-page:hover
                {
                    border: 2px solid #97bc14;
                    background-color: #97bc14;
                    color: #fcffff;
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav ul li ul
                {
                    /*display: none;*/
                    position: absolute;
                    padding-left: 0;
                }

                header #menustrip #menu nav ul li:hover > ul
                {
                    display: inherit;
                }

                    header #menustrip #menu nav ul li ul li
                    {
                        /*left: -100%;*/
                        min-width: 100px;
                        float: none;
                        display: list-item;
                        position: relative;                         
                    }
```

I checked a similar question [CSS Drop Down Menu : nav ul ul li Moved to Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320855/css-drop-down-menu-nav-ul-ul-li-moved-to-right) and checked that `margin` and `padding` were set to `0`. Also in my case, the sub-item moves to the right when hovering, it seems to remain okay while "hidden".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 94 of the CSS file, change `display: inherit;` for `display: block;`. The inherit property is  displaying the dropdown menu as an inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use software Web menu maker & button maker
this software let you to create professional and beautiful menus and buttons with java script or only css.

http://www.easymenumaker.com/